# How to enable and disable network connection when connection to interntet is dropped while everything is logged?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I am trying to create a script that in either Batch, Powershell (Win8.1), or Python(3.4). The script will loop every 15 minutes or so testing if internet connection is still alive. If connection is alive then the script will print Pass with time stamp and be saved to a log file. If internet connection is dead or dropped then script will disable and re-enable network adapter while logging time and test results. I think I have narrowed down a pretty solid batch file.

The problem I'm having is when I run the script with Admin rights allowing the powershell commands to execute, the log file doesn't update. When I run the Batch file without Admin rights the log file updates but the powershell commands don't work.

I have also tried the same script with Command line code in place of the powershell commands I just feel Powershell is faster:

```
netsh interface set interface "Ethernet" DISABLED
netsh interface set interface "Ethernet" ENABLED
```

My code so far:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off

rem Google DNS Most reliable IP for ping testing.
set ip=8.8.8.8

:retest
cls
echo.
echo %TIME%: Testing Internet Connection...

ping -n 1 %ip% | find "TTL"
if not errorlevel 1 set error=Pass
if errorlevel 1 set error=Fail
echo.
echo Time: %TIME% Result: %error%
echo Time: %TIME% Result: %error% >> Server_Restarts.log
echo.
goto %error%

:Pass
echo Retest in 15 minutes..
timeout /T 900 /NOBREAK
goto retest

:Fail
echo Restarting Network..
echo Connection Failed at %TIME%.. >> Server_Restarts.log
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
echo. >> Server_Restarts.log
echo.
echo Restarting Network at Date: %DATE% and Time:%TIME%..
echo Restarting Network at Date: %DATE% and Time:%TIME%.. >> Server_Restarts.log
echo %TIME% Disabling Network Connection..
Powershell.exe Disable-NetAdapter -Name * -Confirm:$false
echo %TIME% Enabling Network Connection..
Powershell.exe Enable-NetAdapter -Name "Ethernet"
echo Network Connection Reset at %TIME%..
echo Network Connection Reset at Date: %DATE% and Time:%TIME%.. >> Server_Restarts.log
echo. >> Server_Restarts.log
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
goto retest
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't write to your file? You're using relative paths, so the location may just be different. If you're right clicking and using "run as admin" it will save the file in `c:\windows\system32\Server_Restarts.log`

Comment: Oh no.. You're so right, I feel so dumb right now.. :( I don't know why I didn't think of that. You're a life saver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using relative paths, so the location may just be different. If you're right clicking and using "run as admin" it will save the file in `c:\windows\system32\Server_Restarts.log`. Use absolute paths for log files or save in the same directory as the batch-file, like this:

```
Time:%TIME%.. >> "%~dp0Server_Restarts.log"
```